# How to call javascript function with alert box in php script?

Tags: javascript, php

I wanted to know if there's a way a javascript function having an alert within, can be called in php. Here's my code but having some trouble to make it work. Help please...

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function call(){
    alert("Successfully Added!");
}
```

php:

```
if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
                    echo call();
                    // echo "call()"; I have tried this too...
                    // die(call()); I have tried this too...
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently trying echo the return value of a php function named call.

Instead you need to echo `<script>` tags and call your javascript function `call()` from inside.

```
if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
  echo "<script>call();</script>";
}
```

It looks like you might eventually be trying to alert something that comes from your database, which means you might be trying to call JavaScript that comes from user input which is a security risk if not handled correctly you could expose yourself to XSS attacks.

Make sure to properly sanitize your user inputs before they are stored in your database and also make sure to properly escape any HTMLbefore adding it to your DOM.

Comment: Yeah. I've tried this. Still, it stores to database successfully, but there's no alert box that came out.

Comment: Then you'll need to show us more of your code.  Does the code that declares the javascript function call() occur on the same page that runs your mysql_query?

Comment: Yes, it's on the same page. Actually I made it with 2 pages at first, but I was instructed to make it in one page. My main purpose here is that, how can I show the pop up message that tells the user that the storing operation is successful without putting the javascript within the php, unless only if by calling the function where the alert is written.

Comment: Can you edit your question or add a fiddle that shows us what your resulting HTML is?

Answer (score 0):

in your php you can use javascripts like this :

```
<?php

if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {

?>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    function call(){
      alert("Successfully Added!");
    }
    call(); //Or what ever you want
 </script>
 <?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's actually working. Actually, that's the first method I made. But we were instructed not to do so. So I'm looking for a way to make this work in a way that the javascript is separated from the php, yet the function can still be called.

Answer (score 0):

Just write echo statement this way.but make sure that your function  must be written in the same file above echo statement.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function call(){
       alert("Successfully Added!");
   }
</script>
 if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
     echo "<script>call();</script>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>
<?php

echo '<script> var popUp=false;</script>';
if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
    echo '<script> popUp=true;</script>';
}
?>
<script>
if(popUp){
    alert('Hi');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```